# C# ASP.NET Core Web API include with where

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a code like this:

```
public Blog GetBlogWithCategoryTagsAndCommentsWithReplies(int id)
    {
        return _context.Blogs
            .Where(blog => blog.Id == id)
            .Include(blog => blog.Category)
            .Include(blog => blog.BlogTags)
                .ThenInclude(blogtag => blogtag.Tag)
            .Include(blog => blog.Comments)
                .ThenInclude(comment => comment.User)
            .Include(blog => blog.Comments)
                .ThenInclude(comment => comment.Replies)
                    .ThenInclude(reply => reply.User)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

works without any problem in this state.

But when I add where to my code, when I make it like

```
public Blog GetBlogWithCategoryTagsAndCommentsWithReplies(int id)
    {
        return _context.Blogs
            .Where(blog => blog.Id == id)
            .Include(blog => blog.Category)
            .Include(blog => blog.BlogTags)
                .ThenInclude(blogtag => blogtag.Tag)
            .Include(blog => blog.Comments.Where(comment=>comment.Confirmation==true))
                .ThenInclude(comment => comment.User)
            .Include(blog => blog.Comments)
                .ThenInclude(comment => comment.Replies.Where(reply=>reply.Confirmation==true))
                    .ThenInclude(reply => reply.User)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

so when I ask comments and replies to return confirmation == true, I get the following error.

Error  : Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: you not be able to perform lambda expression inside include method

Comment: thanks so how should i change the code?

Comment: Please don't post your code in pictures, write it as code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include) is only supported from EF Core v5.0.0, which is in `preview` at this very moment.

If you're using an older EF Core version, you can check some ideas from [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1833).

For instance, if you can afford the performance impact of pulling everything and filtering in memory, you can try to do something like:

```cs
var blog = _context.Blogs
   .Where(blog => blog.Id == id)
   .Include(blog => blog.Category)
   .Include(blog => blog.BlogTags)
      .ThenInclude(blogtag => blogtag.Tag)
   .Include(blog => blog.Comments)
      .ThenInclude(comment => comment.User)
   .Include(blog => blog.Comments)
      .ThenInclude(comment => comment.Replies)
         .ThenInclude(reply => reply.User)
   .FirstOrDefault();

blog.Comments = blog.Comments.Where(comment => comment.Confirmation == true).ToList();

foreach(var comment in blog.Comments)
{
   comment.Replies = comment.Replies.Where(reply => reply.Confirmation == true).ToList();
}

return blog;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Property name as a string.

Like .Include("Category")

You can see overload of the method here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1.include?view=netframework-4.8